# Efficient Progressive Sprinkles Augmentation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have images stored in TFRecord format on which I wish to perform [progressive sprinkles augmentation](https://forums.fast.ai/t/progressive-sprinkles-cutout-variation-my-new-data-augmentation-98-on-nih-malaria-dataset/50454) efficiently in Tensorflow.

Below is the implementation that I have come up with:

```py
class Cutout:
    def __init__(self, num_holes, side_length):
        self.n = num_holes
        self.length = side_length

    def __call__(self, image):
        img_shape = tf.shape(image)
        i = tf.range(img_shape[0])
        j = tf.range(img_shape[1])

        masking_fn = Cutout._mask_out(image, img_shape, i, j, self.length)
        idx = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
        image, idx = tf.while_loop(
                cond=lambda x, ii: tf.less(ii, self.n),
                body=masking_fn,
                loop_vars=[image, idx]
            )
        return image

    @staticmethod
    def _mask_out(image, img_shape, row_range, col_range, hole_length):
        shape = tf.shape(image)
        rows = shape[0]
        cols = shape[1]
        channels = shape[2]

        def _create_hole(image, idx):
            # Masks rows and columns to be replaced

            r = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=rows, dtype=tf.int32)
            c = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=cols, dtype=tf.int32)

            r1 = tf.clip_by_value(r - hole_length // 2, 0, rows)
            r2 = tf.clip_by_value(r + hole_length // 2, 0, rows)
            c1 = tf.clip_by_value(c - hole_length // 2, 0, cols)
            c2 = tf.clip_by_value(c + hole_length // 2, 0, cols)

            row_mask = (r1 <= row_range) & (row_range < r2)
            col_mask = (c1 <= col_range) & (col_range < c2)
            zeros = tf.zeros(shape)

            # Full mask of replaced elements
            mask = row_mask[:, tf.newaxis] & col_mask

            # Select elements from flattened arrays
            img_flat = tf.reshape(image, [-1, channels])
            zeros_flat = tf.reshape(zeros, [-1, channels])
            mask_flat = tf.reshape(mask, [-1])
            result_flat = tf.where(mask_flat, zeros_flat, img_flat)

            # Reshape back
            result = tf.reshape(result_flat, img_shape)
            return [result, idx + 1]

        return _create_hole
```

It works, however, this implementation is terribly inefficient. It takes about 90 seconds to fetch a batch of 32 images (the augmentation is set to 250 holes with a side length of 5) on my machine, compared to less than a second when loading them without any augmentation applied.

I tried using numpy to create a mask since it's more efficient but it isn't able to work without knowing the shape of the image beforehand. The call to `tf.shape(image)` would contain shape information at runtime (when the graph is executed in a session), however, numpy requires those values upfront to create a tensor.

Comment: Did the answer provided help for your situation? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, please let me know where it falls short and I will try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I did this in Tensorflow 2.1, so there might be some differences in syntax (I know I used `tf.random.uniform()` instead of `tf.random_uniform()` for instance). I tried to basically let TF do all the heavy lifting without using any explicit loops.

Code below, followed by a timing comparison. Mine ends up being more than 10x faster on my machine.

```
class Cutout:

    def __init__(self, num_holes, side_length):
        self.n = num_holes
        self.length = side_length

    def __call__(self, image):
        tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        zeros = tf.zeros_like(image)  # used in last step
        img_shape = tf.shape(image)
        rows = img_shape[0]
        cols = img_shape[1]
        num_channels = img_shape[-1]

        # We want to build all combinations of indices in any hole.
        # Here I create `n` tiles of all row/col indices, basically handling
        # each hole in a different layer of the resulting tensor.
        row_range = tf.tile(tf.range(rows)[..., tf.newaxis], [1, self.n])
        col_range = tf.tile(tf.range(cols)[..., tf.newaxis], [1, self.n])

        # Generate all of our starting indices at once.
        r_idx = tf.random.uniform([self.n], minval=0, maxval=rows-1, dtype=tf.int32)
        c_idx = tf.random.uniform([self.n], minval=0, maxval=cols-1, dtype=tf.int32)

        # With broadcasting, these operations work for our tensor of
        # `n` row/column center points.
        r1 = tf.clip_by_value(r_idx - self.length // 2, 0, rows)
        r2 = tf.clip_by_value(r_idx + self.length // 2, 0, rows)
        c1 = tf.clip_by_value(c_idx - self.length // 2, 0, cols)
        c2 = tf.clip_by_value(c_idx + self.length // 2, 0, cols)

        # By refactoring here, we can take advantage of broadcasting
        # to build masks for each hole, one per layer in the last
        # dimension of our resulting masks
        row_mask = (row_range > r1) & (row_range < r2)
        col_mask = (col_range > c1) & (col_range < c2)

        mask = row_mask[:, tf.newaxis] & col_mask
        mask = tf.reduce_any(mask, axis=-1)  # Combine mask layers into one
        mask = mask[..., tf.newaxis]  # Copy mask across channels
        mask = tf.tile(mask, [1, 1, num_channels])

        # Finally we apply our mask with `tf.where`.
        filtered_image = tf.where(mask, zeros, image)
        return filtered_image
```

Using your script with 100 chips and a chip width of 10 I get:

[image]

```
# 355 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using my code with 100 chips, chip width of 10:

[image]

```
# 28.5 ms ± 2.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**More than 10 times faster!**

**Edit:** I created a Python package and will be maintaining it [on GitHub](https://github.com/Engineero/tf_sprinkles). You can install the package with `pip install tf-sprinkles` and should be able to put it in your data ingest pipeline. There's a `mode` flag that let's you specify if you want to fill the sprinkles with Gaussian noise or make them randomly black/white instead of all black.

Comment: Could you please take a look into this issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv/issues/134